# unzip a file then change ownership

Tags: php, zip, unzip, ownership

I have a number of files in a zip on my server.  I then use this script to extract them:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($file_root."/install.zip") === TRUE) 
{
    $zip->extractTo($file_root."/");
    $zip->close();
}
```

The problem is that the ownership of these files is set to "nobody" and I need them to be changed so we can edit the files via FTP.

I've done a fair bit of research and cant find an answer anywhere, please help.

Comment: Try using PHP's [`chown`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) command.  PHP may or may not have permission to do this, though.

Comment: or change your apache handlers to suPHP from within cpanel, this will fix your problem: more info about the different handlers can be found here:http://boomshadow.net/tech/php-handlers/

Answer (score 0):

ZIP files do not support Unix-style ownership information, and Apache could not create files with an ownership other than whatever ID it's running as anyways. You'll have to use `chown` elsewhere with elevated privileges to change the ownership away from 'nobody'. This could be done from Apache using sudo, though you shouldn't ever elevate Apache's privileges in this way. It runs as a reduced privilege user for a reason.